# Retrieve the pull requests with search criteria using Azure DevOps Python Api

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am in need to retrieve all pull requests that have been completed.  I am having difficulty providing search criteria using the Microsoft Azure Devops API in python.  I'm trying to locate all the pull requests in the Azure Devops repositories with a  search_criteria='completed'.  Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could list all completed pull request via this REST API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=completed&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Python Script

```
import requests
import base64
pat = 'PAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}
response = requests.get(
    url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=completed&api-version=6.1-preview.1", headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Comment: how to achieve it using azure devops python api instead of request library.

Comment: Hi @RajendraKumar, check this [Azure DevOps Python API doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api): This Python library provides a thin wrapper around the Azure DevOps REST APIs. See the Azure DevOps REST API reference for details on calling different APIs.